# How to solve max flow problem with two independent constraints?

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, algorithms

The general problem of max flow is to compute maximum flow you can pass through the network. But what if I have two variables on each edge $(p_i, q_i)$ and I should find maximum flow w.r.t. $p$ but so that all other $q$-s will not overflow at some point?

Comment: how is that different from just saying that the capacity of each edge is $\min\{p_e,q_e\}$?

Comment: So in fact I want to find max-flow in such a graph (kind of bipartite) where there is only one source $s$ which goes to the first part of graph with different vertices ${a_1, a_2, ..., a_n}$ which go to other part of graph with vertices ${b_1, b_2, ..., b_m}$ which go to the target vertex $t$. As long as the constraints are different on each edge it may happen that if we take only $p$'s then we can miss such a situation when we have $q_i > p_i$ on some edges and on the following $q_i < p_i$ which effectively means that $p$'s will pass but $q$'s will not.

Comment: If $q_i > p_i$ for some edge $i$, then when you find the max flow w.r.t $p$, the flow through $i$ will never exceed $p_i$, so it will never exceed $q_i$. So this case is fine. The only other case is where $q_i \leq p_i$, in which case you should have taken $\min \{p_i, q_i\}$?